# Zeroes of a holomorphic map $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}$ for $n\geq 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Why can the zeros of a holomorphic map $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}$ with $n\geq 2$ have no isolated zeros (or poles if we write it as meromorphic)?

Someone says the $n$-times Cauchy Integral formula is enough, but how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the Weierstrass Preparation Theorem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem. If you still believe in books, any book on several complex variables will address this; it's also discussed on pp. 7-9 of Griffiths and Harris.

Answer (score 1):

Ted is of course perfectly correct. :)

Alternatively the claim follows from Hartogs' theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%27_extension_theorem, whose proof may be the origin of the Cauchy integral formula hint you received.

Comment: Great point. Yes, good old contrapositive. :) My answer gives a lot more structure than is needed here.